# Running more than 10 routes at same time in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

My team and I are trying to run food collection routes for a food bank in Mexico City but we can run more than 10 routes at a time. In order to run the eleventh we need to take one out.

Does someone know what could be the problem or where to configure this?

Comment: Do you mean to say you cannot run more than 10 routes at a time?  Just wanted to make sure that was a typo.  If so, please edit.